# Single prediction using a model pre-trained with scaled features

Tags: scikit-learn, persistence, svm, prediction

I trained a SVM scikit-learn model with scaled features and persist it to be used later. In another file I loaded the saved model and I want to submit a new set of features to perform a prediction. Do I have to scale this new set of features? How can I do this with only one set of features?

I am not scaling the new values and I am getting weird outcomes and I cannot do the predictions. Despite of this, the prediction with a large test set generated by StratifiedShuffleSplit is working fine and I am getting a 97% of accuracy.

The problem is with the single predictions using a persisted SVM model trained with scaled features. Some idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could include your test features in the scaling process, so that you scale over the union of test and train test. Maybe this helps. The missing accuracy in your test set could also be a problem of the structure of your test set, did you run cross validation? that means you run it with different train and test sets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should absolutely perform the same scaling on the new data. However, this might be impossible if you haven't saved the scaler you trained before.

This is why instead of training and saving your SVM, you should train and save your scaler with your SVM together. In the machine learning jargon, this is called a Pipeline.

This is how you would use it on a toy example:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = load_breast_cancer()
X, y = data.data, data.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler',StandardScaler()), ('svc', SVC())])
```

This pipeline then supports the same operations as a regular `scikit-learn` model:

```
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.score(X_test, y_test)
```

When fitting the `pipe`, it first scales and then feeds the scaled features into the classifier.

Once it is trained, you can save the `pipe` object just like you saved the SVM before. When you will load it and apply it to new data, it will do the scaling as desired before the predictions.